# What is the max array size in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to figure out what the max array size in Firestore is for a bloom filter I'm implementing and I am sort of confused on the documentation. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes) is a quota that I think might be it: 40,000 indexes per document. It has to do with searching and since I will be searching against the array `.where("array.458", "==", "false")`, 40,000 - other indexes in document, is my best guess. The array will be of booleans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure you're describing in your question doesn't appear to be an array.  It's a map.  When you use the dot notation like this:

```
.where("array.458", "==", "false")
```

That's looking for a property called "458" in a map field called "array".

There are no limits to the number of properties in a map, but there are [limits to how big a document can be](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields).  You're limited to 1 MB of total data per document, so your map will run out of space (and writes will fail) when its data pushes past that limit.

Incidentally, if you did actually have an array, the number of items it could contain would also be limited by the size of the document.